# query for word/string having two or more spaces in it

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have words like :

1) word : "Fourscore and seven years ago"
2) word : "Down the street" 
3) word : "apple"
4) word : "The beach"
....

Here I am trying to filter out the words having two or more spaces containing in it

expected results are 1) and 2)

I have tried something like this after referring the reg ex for two or more spaces in a string:

```
[
    {
        '$match': {
            'word': '/[ ]{2,}/'
        }
    }
]
```

But this didn't work , Any guiding links or a solution would be much helpful....TIA

Comment: Try using the `$regex` operator instead of `$match`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, its just that your regexp is not accurate enough.

Currently your regexp is match sentences with a double space in them like: `example  one` would be matched.

You want to use something like this:

```
[
    {
        '$match': {
            'word': / .* /
        }
    }
]
```

I recommend trying [this](https://regex101.com/) site to test your future regex's to make sure they're doing what you intend them to.

Comment: Thanks tom , but please could you elaborate how this regex matches two or more spaces ? (as there is no number included or an expression though) , little confused ....hope you got this

Comment: The regexp I posted searches for a "space" "anything zero or more times" "space" combination, which i'm assuming is pretty self explanatory on to why it requires at least two spaces. you should read up about javascript regexp there is quite a lot of documentation about the subject.

Comment: I think its also worthy to not that `.*` uses what we call "greedy matching" hence making the regexp work as required.

Comment: After going through regex i have understood `/ .{2,}/` but this also matches one space

Comment: deep concept.....I just figured out the solution as `[{$match: {
  'word': / .+ /
}}]`

Comment: This is fine but it will not allow double space like `word"space""space"word2`.

Comment: yeah this is correct !! but luckily i don't have multiple spaces(xspacespacey...) , but yeah this makes sense.....so an apropriate solution would be?

Comment: My answer should cover all of the cases, can you explain why you're not happy with it? did i misunderstand something?

Comment: yeah i actually want results of two or more spaces in a string (if it has only one space or no space reject them) as i have mentioned in expected output in Q

Comment: I understand,  `/ .* /` gives you exactly that?

Comment: yeah , as this search for 1st space and ends till the end of the string and starts from back finds 2nd space so here my condition becomes true if space exists or false.......https://javascript.info/regexp-greedy-and-lazy#greedy-search

Comment: I just read the greedy search from the link , they have given such a wonderful example and came out with that solution ......hope I'm correct with that